# How detect touch when i use on_click

Tags: python

Hi how can I detect my touch with touchframe?

The first time the mouse worked OK when I connected my frame, touched the cursor ran and clicked. But this code fragment event didn't work. Why? How can I change the code to detect the touch event?

```
def on_click(x,y,button,pressed):
    print("mouse click")
    playerOff()
    listener.stop()
```